# Can you play Dixit cooperatively with only 2 players?

Tags: house-rules, dixit, two-player

My son (age 5) enjoys Dixit, but often it's just the two of us. I've come up with my own variant, below, but I want to hear more from the community.

We play with a hand of four cards, and we take turns as active player. The active player gives a hint, as normal, and plays a card face-down. The other player plays, and then two cards from the top of the deck are added to the mix before we shuffle and deal face-up. We play co-op, aiming to have us both guess correctly what the other player chose.

Comment: I really like this question, but because of the amount of possible answers it's more suited for a forum and not a Q&A site, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @freekvd - Agreed, but it feels like it could be narrowed down, and it already has a decent answer.

Comment: I re-worded the question. Ones with "best" are considered "subjective" and often get closed. I made the question a yes-or-no question that can be answered "objectively."

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't sound too bad, except that the drawn cards could be really off.

Alternatively, you could try to play a cooperative variant.
These two are interesting:

> The game is cooperative. Each player is the storyteller five times for
>   a total of 10 turns and you go for a high score. The highest possible
>   is
>   70.
>
> Neither player has a hand. Each turn, the storyteller makes up a story
>   without seeing any cards, and then six cards are flipped over from the
>   deck and arranged. Both players (must?) vote for two cards that they
>   think best match the description, and color matters: use the red peg
>   for your 1st vote, and the green peg for your 2nd vote. Then players
>   reveal their votes.
>
> For a card where you both voted red, you get 4 points. For a card
>   where you both voted green, you get 3 points. For a card where you
>   both voted but the colors didn't match, you get 2 points. For a card
>   where only one player voted for it, you lose a point.

Source: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/700350/2-player-cooperative-dixit

> How to Play
>
> - Deal cards to each player as usual.
> - Pick a scoring marker for the players (just one marker) and another as a failure marker.
> - Pick a player to be Storyteller first. I'll refer to 'Storyteller' and 'Player 2'.
> - The Storyteller picks a card from their hand and gives a clue or tells a story about it, then places the card face down.
> - Player 2 picks a card from their hand to try to match the clue.
> - Add 4 random cards from the deck to the chosen cards.
> - Shuffle them out and places them on the table as usual.
> - Each player now secretly makes a guess. The Storyteller wants to find Player 2s card. Player 2 wants to find the Storyteller's card.
>
> Reveal your guesses!
>
> If you both guessed the other player's card correctly, cheer and
>   advance your scoring marker 1 space.
>
> If either or both of you guessed wrong, pout and advance the failure
>   marker one space.
>
> Each draw a new card. If you still have 4 cards left in the deck, swap
>   who is Storyteller and proceed to another round.
>
> Try to have more points than failures at the end of the game!
>
> What does this mean? When you are the Storyteller, you want Player 2
>   to guess your card. This is easy. You could just say "A city made out
>   of eggs", and your partner is sure to guess it.
>
> But...you also want to guess Player 2's card. Give a clue too
>   specific, and your partner won't be able to play any card you can
>   recognize!
>
> You need to give them enough room to play a card you recognize,
>   without making it too easy to be fooled by a random card.
>
> Spirit of the game: No giving "double" clues that are meant to
>   describe your card and the card Player 2 is supposed to play
>   separately. ("My card is a scarecrow, but your card has plants").
>
> No setting up codes.
>
> No repeating clues.
>
> Remember, you are trying to play a 4+ player competitive game as a 2
>   player co-op. Try to break the game and it will break. Go with it and
>   have fun and it should provide some amusement. I've tried to make it
>   resistant to "casual" abuse at least.

Source: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/676496/2-player-co-op-dixit-variant